# styleManager: problem using setStyleDeclaration

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, coding-style

Hey folks..!!
I m using styleManager.setStyleDeclaration to set the CssStyleDeclaration object for more then one instance of the same component, that is being used in different canvases.
I want to set different properties of this component in various canvases, but it wont happen as setStyleDeclaration takes name of the component and set styles to it globally, i suppose.
 
following is the first **cssstyledeclaration**:

```
this.dataTickerOddStyle = new CSSStyleDeclaration();
        this.dataTickerOddStyle.setStyle("fillColors", StringUtilEx.ExtractColorPair(o.DataTicker.Item[0].Background_Fill_Colors));
        this.dataTickerOddStyle.setStyle("fillAlphas", StringUtilEx.ExtractNumberPair(o.DataTicker.Item[0].Background_Fill_Alphas));
        this.dataTickerOddStyle.setStyle("gradientRatio", StringUtilEx.ExtractNumberPair(o.DataTicker.Item[0].Background_Gradient_Ratios));
        this.dataTickerOddStyle.setStyle("cornerRadius", int(o.DataTicker.Item[0].Background_Corner_Radius));
        this.dataTickerOddStyle.setStyle("borderColor", StringUtilEx.ConvertToColor(o.DataTicker.Item[0].Background_Border_Color));
        this.dataTickerOddStyle.setStyle("borderThickness", Number(o.DataTicker.Item[0].Background_Border_Thickness));<br>
```

This is how i ve used it:

```
this.styleManager.setStyleDeclaration("com.GradientCanvas",WidgetStylesheet.instance.dataTickerOddStyle, true);
```

and another **cssstyledeclaration** is:

```
this.m_zoneBackgroundStyle = new CSSStyleDeclaration();
        this.m_zoneBackgroundStyle.setStyle("fillAlphas", StringUtilEx.ExtractNumberPair(o["Background_Fill_Alphas"]));
        this.m_zoneBackgroundStyle.setStyle("fillColors", StringUtilEx.ExtractColorPair(o["Background_Fill_Colors"]));
        this.m_zoneBackgroundStyle.setStyle("gradientRatio", StringUtilEx.ExtractNumberPair(o["Background_Gradient_Ratios"]));
        this.m_zoneBackgroundStyle.setStyle("borderColor", StringUtilEx.ConvertToColor(o["Background_Border_Color"]));
        this.m_zoneBackgroundStyle.setStyle("borderThickness", Number(o["Background_Border_Thickness"]));
        this.m_zoneBackgroundStyle.setStyle("cornerRadius", Number(o["Background_Corner_Radius"]));
```

and for this i use following:

```
this.fill.styleManager.setStyleDeclaration("com.GradientCanvas", AppStylesheet.instance.m_zoneBackgroundStyle, true);<br>
```

Notice that i m using same selector/component..Please help me out on this..thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem. I was using `Type Selector` before, instead of `Class Selector`.

Answer (score 0):

(not sure I fully understand what you're getting at.. but.. )

You can set the style on a single component instance without changing the global style.

```
component.setStyle( ... )
```

instead of

```
CSSStyleDeclaration.setStyle( ... )
```

Comment: Thanx for the answer. I resolved the problem..was using Type Selector before, instead of Class Selector.